# Value of the integration $L=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1+x^8} dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Given $$L=\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1}{1+x^8} dx$$
Then,

1. $L<1$
2. $L>1$
3. $L<\pi/4$
4. $L>\pi/4$

Which options are true. I concluded that $1$ is true as $\frac{1}{1+x^8}\leq 1$. But I am not able to conclude between $3$ and $4$. How to solve this kind of integrations?

Comment: Ok did it @NormalHuman

Comment: Note that if Option $3$ is true, then certainly Option $1$ is also true.  If Option $2$ is true, then certainly Option $4$ is true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: if $x \in (0, 1)$, then 
$$\frac{1}{1 + x^8} > \frac{1}{1 + x^2}.$$

Comment: Got it , thanks

Comment: $\Delta = 3 $ seconds.

Comment: Yup that was indeed tight :) @martycohen

Comment: Well done!  +1 . - Mark

Answer (score 3):

Since
$x^2 > x^8$
on $(0, 1)$,
$L
=\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1}{1+x^8} dx
>\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1}{1+x^2} dx
=\frac{\pi}{4}
$.

Comment: Well done!  +1 . - Mark